# CentOS 7 NFSv4 server + Fedora 30 NFSv4 client: command 'quota' does not work

Tags: centos7, nfs, fedora, nfs4, quota

I've got a CentOS 7 box serving NFSv3/4 exports - the served filesystem (users' home directories) is an ext4 partition (so, no XFS, which I get is more complicated for quotas) configured with *usrquota* which correctly returns per-user quota's when logged on it:

```sh
[XXXXXXX@YYYYYY ~]$ quota
Disk quotas for user XXXXXXX (uid 12345):
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
      /dev/sdb1 134198592  145000000 150000000         1804006       0       0
```

The **rpc-rquotad** daemon is installed on this server to make `quota` work when the user is logged on the CentOS 5 box (old, I know) via an NFSv3 export:

```sh
[XXXXXXX@ZZZZZZ ~]$ quota
Disk quotas for user XXXXXXX (uid 12345):
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
ZZZZZZ:/apotto/home1
                134198632  145000000 150000000         1804008       0       0
```

On Fedora 30 clients that import the same home directory from the same server via NFSv4, everything works perfectly EXCEPT the same `quota` command, which returns nothing; SELinux enabled or disabled on the clients does not make any difference, as well as 'firewalld' running or not.

The ONLY vaguely relevant search that turns up on Google seems to be [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/890323) from the Red Hat Knowledgebase which I cannot read without subscription.

Any advice?

P.S.: I just noticed that, on another cluster with an identical setup but CentOS 7 clients, whenever `quota` is issued, at least this appears in the journal of the server machine:

```
set 09 12:41:59 WWWWWWWWWWW rpc.rquotad[267549]: Cannot stat() given mountpoint /home1: No such file or directory
set 09 12:41:59 WWWWWWWWWWW rpc.rquotad[267549]: Skipping...
```

Comment: The Red Hat article you linked to describes a bug in ONTAP, the OS that runs NetApp storage servers. It is probably not relevant if your NFS server is not such a machine. But just in case, it suggests using `quota -m` as a workaround for that bug.

Comment: Thanks for your help; it's not clear to me how `quota -m` is to be used - the command issued 'as-is' does not return anything, just like simple `quota` did.
I read quota's man and in the `-m` paragraph NFSv4 is mentioned but I'm sorry to admit I'm not getting what the option is about...